# Can't resolve dependency conflicts while migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, npm, migration

I'm following [this guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html) and have gone through step three, changing the vue version directly in package.json. After updating package.json, I tried to run `npm install` to apply my changes, but I'm getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: vite-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.7.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@"^3.0.0 || ^2.0.0" from vue-axios@3.5.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/vue-axios
npm ERR!     vue-axios@"^3.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vue@"~2" from @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@2.0.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
npm ERR!     @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@"^2.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   3 more (@vitejs/plugin-vue2, @vue/babel-preset-jsx, the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @vue/compat@"^3.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vue@3.2.47
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@"3.2.47" from @vue/compat@3.2.47
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/compat
npm ERR!     @vue/compat@"^3.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I've tried uninstalling the packages with the dependency on vue@2.7.14, both via command line and by simply removing them from package.json, but whatever I do, it just spits this exact same error back at me. How can I resolve this, and is there a better approach to this migration to avoid all this headache?

Answer (score 0):

try `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm i`